# How to show invalid input

Tags: python-3.x, user-input, try-except, invalidoperationexception

My task is:

*Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.*

I want to ignore any invalid integer and print '**Invalid Output**' message after calculating the maximum and minimum number.But it always prints the invalid message right after user input. How am i supposed to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        n = int(num)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
    if largest is None:
        largest=n
    elif n>largest:
        largest=n
    elif smallest is None:
        smallest=n
    elif n<smallest:
        smallest=n
print("Maximum", largest)
print('Minimum', smallest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store that `invalid output` as a boolean variable

```py
largest = None
smallest = None
is_invalid=False
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        n = int(num)
    except:
        is_invalid=True
    if largest is None:
        largest=n
    elif n>largest:
        largest=n
    elif smallest is None:
        smallest=n
    elif n<smallest:
        smallest=n
print("Maximum", largest)
print('Minimum', smallest)
if is_invalid:
    print('Invalid Input')
```

Comment: No, to avoid invalid input i used try and except. @Arun T

Comment: @RifatAbdurRahman This works because when i enter `bob` as input it gives me an error. This would make the input invalid

Comment: Oh sorry. Mr. Arun T was right. Since is_invalid hasn't changed its value, output will show invalid message if i input a valid argument (integer).
Changing "is_invalid=False" at the beginning works though.

Comment: yeah, i meant to put it false but i messed up. sorry, editing it now

Answer (score 0):

This can be one solution

```
largest = None
smallest = None
errors = False
while True:
    num = input('Please type a number : ')
    if num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        number = int(num)
        #your logical operations and assignments here
    except ValueError:
        errors = True
        continue
if errors:
    print('Invalid input')
else:
    print('Your Results')
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This doesn't do what he wants. He wants to notify the user that he entered invalid input at the end.

Comment: @AtharvaKadlag sorry thought it was for every input will be altering it now

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with lists,you can use list to solve your problem effectively,
here is a modified version of your code which uses list,

```
num1=[]
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    num1.append(num)
    if num == "done":
        break

for i in num1:
    try:
        i = int(i)
    except:
        print('Invalid input:',i)
        num1.remove(i)

print("Maximum", max(num1))
print('Minimum', min(num1))
```

output:

```
Enter a number: 34
Enter a number: 57
Enter a number: 89
Enter a number: ds
Enter a number: 34
Enter a number: do
Enter a number: done

Invalid input: ds
Invalid input: do
Maximum 89
Minimum 34
```

hope this helps,let me know if anything is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the (int) in try block. Because you want only integer input in try block so if does not satisfy the condition of integer input it will execute the except block.

Your code should look like this in try block:
try:
   n = num